# Extract images from a document and add their filepaths as a caption

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

I have 200 Word documents that include multiple images. I'm looking for a way to automatically put the filepaths of the images below them.

I currently:

1. Save the DOCX file as an HTML file to extract the images
2. Locate the folder of the saved images and copy their filepaths individually
3. Paste the filepath below each image in the DOCX file in the format

I'm doing this because the flashcard program (Anki) that I use for med school can only import images as filepaths.

This is code written by Doug Robbins that I found in the MS Word forums. I think it's similar to what I need but I want to select all images instead of one at a time.

```vb
Dim strImage As String
Dim ils As InlineShape
Dim FD As FileDialog

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .Title = "Select the image that you want to insert."
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewLargeIcons
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show = -1 Then
        strImage = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "You did not select an image."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Set ils = Selection.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strImage, True)

ils.Select

Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Selection.InsertAfter vbCr & strImage
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and link your images when placing them in Word, instead of embedding them. In the *Insert Picture* dialog, the **Insert** button is a dropdown. Click on the arrow and choose **Link to File** or **Link and Insert**. Then the code to retrieve the path is as simple as:

```
Sub GetFullPath()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim PicPath As String

    PicPath = Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    PicPath = Selection.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    MsgBox PicPath
End Sub
```

There are two statements in there, you only need 1, depending on whether your pictures float or are inline with text.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your code and achieved what I wanted. It turns out saving the document as Web Page, Filtered links all the images to the file. Thank you!

```html
Sub GetFullPath()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim PicPath As String

    PicPath = Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    PicPath = Selection.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName

    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    Selection.InsertAfter vbCr & "<img src=" & Chr(34) & PicPath & Chr(34) & ">"

    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```